SwiftUI TextEditor bound to $[Note].content — slow performance?
I'm building simple text editor, which can handle several opened files. I have NotesManager, which stores all opened documents, and I pass binding to each of these notes to views using NavigationLink.
For some reason text field updates very slow on fast inserts even on small files (like 20 lines).

Is it supposed to work so slowly or I'm missing some tagging // lazy updates approach?
If it's SwiftUI limitation, should I use AppKit without reactive binding to archieve desired performance?

Here is the demo of slow redraw:

NotesManager.swift
class NotesManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var notes: [Note] = []
    
    var fileMonitors: [UUID: DispatchSourceFileSystemObject] = [:]

    func add(note: Note) {
        notes.append(note)
        monitorFile(for: note)
    }

    private func monitorFile(for note: Note) {
        ...
    }

    private func loadFileContent(for note: Note) {
        ...
        add(note)
    }
    
    ...
}

ContentView.swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedNoteID: UUID?
    @EnvironmentObject var notesManager: NotesManager
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List($notesManager.notes, selection: $selectedNoteID) { $note in
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    TextEditorView(note: $note)
                        .frame(minWidth: 400, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 400, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }) {
                    SidebarItemView(note: note, selectedNoteID: $selectedNoteID)
                        .tag(note.id)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Open document to get started")
        }
    }
}

TextEditorView.swift
// Using CodeEditorView package

struct TextEditorView: View {
    @Binding var note: Note
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var searchQuery: String = ""
    @State private var messages: Set<TextLocated<Message>> = Set ()
    @State private var editPosition: CodeEditor.Position = CodeEditor.Position()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CodeEditor(text: $note.content, position: $editPosition, messages: $messages, language: .swift())
                .tag(note.id)
//                  .environment(\.codeEditorTheme, colorScheme == .dark ? Theme.defaultDark : Theme.defaultLight)
        }
        
    }
}


Why are you using id(UUID())? This guarantees the entire list will be rerendered on every update.

.id(UUID()) looks like the problem

Good catch! Left from some experiments, fixed the code.
However, redraw glitches still are here :(. Any other ideas? I've added GIF with showcase.

The text editor is directly modifying the Notes array in NotesManager, which propagates a view update through the entire hierarchy, including the NavigationSplitView.
We can improve performance by segregating TextEditorView's Note-binding from NotesManager's Published Note array.
I see two approaches:

Separate the Note's content from NotesManager's Published property (e.g have a published array of Note IDs and a Note storage which is not published)
Separate the single note being updated from the list (e.g create a copy as State for TextEditorView and update the list purposefully at certain intervals or events, e.g when typing stops).

